php include with or without ending ;
I am learning PHP and I am testing that when including file it works with or without the ; symbol but my question is:
Which one is the correct way of the following two working options?
(with or without the ending ;)
<?php include('/folder/file.php')?>

or
<?php include('/folder/file.php');?>

What problems could exist if using one but no the other?

If you only have a single statement inside the <?php your-statement ?>, then you don't need the ;. If you have multiple statements <?php statement1; statement2; ?> , you need to separate them with ;. So it's up to you if you want to add it or not if you only have one statement.

Det var så lite så!

But put the ; in so when you decide to add another statement, you dont miss it out
